# Do bare protons exist, even transiently, in aqueous solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry

Generally $\ce{H^+}$ ions in water remain in the form of hydronium ions ($\ce{H3O+}$), and not as "free" aqueous protons, as far as I've been taught.

My question: is this always the case, even when considering dynamics at extremely short time scales? By this I am not meaning interconversion with the Zundel ($\ce{H5O2+}$) or other states. I mean to say, does bare $\ce{H+}(\mathrm{aq})$ ever exist  on, say, a femtosecond time scale?

Comment: I think this is one of those things where there probably is a single proton floating around somewhere in a solution, but the formation of this is so unlikely. It means that you need to have just a hydrogen atom somewhere in solution and some other molecule which will take that electron and form a radical, which is certainly not stabilizing. Then, the proton needs to somehow not react with anything for a femtosecond. My bet is that this just doesn't happen...

Comment: This is probably more of a philosophical question - when is a H bonded to something,  and when is it not?  That's quite tricky to answer,  particularly in the liquid state...

Comment: Relevant: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32558/why-are-hydrogen-ions-always-associated-with-another-molecule/32559#32559

Answer (score 15):

According to [Myths about the proton. The nature of H+ in condensed media](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/9m11233k#page-1) Accounts of Chemical Research, vol. 46, pp 2567–2575:

> But to put this into
>   perspective, an electron-free proton has an estimated acidity $10^{56}$(!) times greater than 100%
>   H2SO4, the threshold of superacidity.$^2$ Adding a bare proton to a molecule is a real event in the
>   gas phase but only a *solvated* hydrogen ion can be transferred in condensed phases.

Answer (score 7):

No.
The proton is always within some electron density, even when transitioning between the hydronium/water and whatever anion it was bonded with.

Comment: To expand on this answer:  Say a proton moves from one water molecule to another.  It does not jump off and become a bare proton, even for a moment.  Rather the second water molecule begins to form a bond with the proton as the first water molecule begins to loosen, leading to a transition state where the proton is partially bonded to both water molecules.